# PHP how to find same values in column

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Hi i'm quite newbie in php language and i need to find same values in DESCRIPTION column in my database table.

id-------DESCRIPTION

1-------Final

2-------Exam

3-------Test

4-------Test

5-------Mid

6-------Quiz

7-------Quiz

As output it needs to be like:

Final

Exam

**Test**

**Test**

Mid

**Quiz**

**Quiz**

If a value repating just change them style is enough but i'm really don't know how to do it.

```
<?php

$check = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM EXAMS");
while($test=mysqli_fetch_array($check))
{

    echo $test["DESCRIPTION"];
}



?>
```

Comment: So you want to output duplicate values in bold?

Comment: Yes but it needs to be programaticly not like if(description=="test") because value can be change and writing if for all of one is quite lame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) subquery to look if the same value *exists* for another `id`:

```
$result = $connection->query("
    SELECT e.id, e.DESCRIPTION, EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM EXAMS e2 
        WHERE e2.DESCRIPTION = e.DESCRIPTION
          AND e2.id <> e.id
    ) as is_duplicate
    FROM EXAMS e
    ORDER BY e.id
");
```

Then check in PHP if it is a duplicate (`if ($row['is_duplicate'] == 1)`) and mark it bold:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ($row['is_duplicate'] == 1) {
        echo "<strong>$row['DESCRIPTION']</strong><br>";
    } else {
        echo "$row['DESCRIPTION']<br>";
    }
}
```

#### PHP solution

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM EXAMS");

$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($data, 'DESCRIPTION'));

foreach($data as $row)
{
    if ($counts[$row['DESCRIPTION']] > 1) {
        echo "<strong>$row['DESCRIPTION']</strong><br>";
    } else {
        echo "$row['DESCRIPTION']<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what if i use loop in while?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `while` **is** a *loop*.

Comment: Yeah in background i execute an exec query so i couldn't change sql. What if i assign all values in array in while. then using foreach find same values and change make them bold.

Comment: So you need a pure PHP solution?

Comment: Yes but i'm really don't know how to do it.